# API to retrieve answers for general questions

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, natural-language-processing

I was looking for a service (with API) where I can ask it a general question (aka, when was Einstein born?) and retrieve an answer from the Web.

Is there any available service to do that? Have tried Watson services but didn't work as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for software are off-topic. Try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @DavidRicherby Computer science people can answer this kind of questions, not software users.

Comment: You have asked about API or service so this is off-topic here and the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) seems fitting.